# combine does not change the locale name

Tags: c++

For the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc = std::locale()
        .combine<std::numpunct<char>>(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
    std::cout << loc.name() << '\n';

    std::cout << (std::locale() == loc);
}
```

When compiled with gcc and clang, the output is `C` and `1` (https://godbolt.org/z/q8fT4oqj3). But cppreference says that [`combine()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/combine) will return a new, nameless locale.

I am totally confused:

1. If `combine()` returns a nameless locale, then why is the locale's name still 'C'?
2. If `operator==` returns `1`, then how to distinguish between them?

Comment: On godbolt clang uses gcc libstdc++ by default. You need to explicitly specify `-stdlib=libc++` to build with clang standard library. and clang outputs `* 0` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should return `"*"` according to the standard:

> ```
> template <class Facet> locale combine(const locale& other) const;
> ```
>
> 1. Effects: Constructs a locale incorporating all facets from `*this` except for that one facet of other that is identified by `Facet`.
> 2. Returns: The newly created locale.
> 3. Throws: `runtime_error` if `has_facet<Facet>(other)` is false.
> 4. Remarks: **The resulting locale has no name.**

> ```
> basic_string<char> name() const;
> ```
>
> 5. Returns: The name of `*this`, if it has one; **otherwise, the string `"*"`**. If `*this` has a name, then `locale(name().c_str())` is
>    equivalent to `*this`. Details of the contents of the resulting string
>    are otherwise implementation-defined.

So it looks like a bug.